# Have Arduino write data to a MySQL database?

Tags: datalogging

Would it be possible to have an Arduino write directly to a MySQL database?

I'm a web programmer, so I'm familiar with how to get records from a MySQL database. I have MAMP installed on my mac, so I have the ability to build an interface, directly in the web browser, that retrives the records from a MySQL database.

What I'm thinking is to connect the Arduino directly to my computer via USB, and write data from the sensors, or the pins, directly to my MySQL database.

I'm using two phototransistor to record whenever something blocks the light. Each sensor records individually a timestamp for when the blocking occur.

Is that possible?

Comment: This looks like a project that will do what you are looking for https://launchpad.net/mysql-arduino

Answer (score 4):

It's possible if you forget about the Arduino directly writing to the database.

Simply put, the Arduino is restricted to a serial connection.  To directly communicate with MySQL you would need a network connection, and then implement the MySQL protocol - a huuuge amount of work.

The normal way is to have an adapter program running on the PC which receives data from the Arduino over the serial connection, then performs any insert, select, etc instructions on the MySQL for you.

There is a "MySQL Connector" available* (https://launchpad.net/mysql-arduino) but of course that requires you to have an active network connection of some form to your Arduino.  Remember that the Arduino (certainly the Uno) is very limited on memory and program space, so having the Arduino connect direct, and doing anything else, might be mutually exclusive.

---

*Nice find, @SomeHardwareGuy...

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using an Arduino Yun: the Yun has a linux cpu paired with the ATMega32U4, so you can delegate things like accessing a mysql database, either local or remote.

Take a look at this [instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Access-of-Arduino-Y%C3%9AN-with-MySQL-PHP5-and-/?ALLSTEPS).

There are different ways for delegating logging sensors readings to the linux side and have them stored on a mysql: the easiest is to code a short python script and call it from the sketch using [Process](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Process).